# Ubuntu 14.04.5 can't install proprietary drivers

Tags: drivers, fglrx, amd-graphics, proprietary

I'm unable to install my AMD proprietary Drivers in Ubuntu 14.04.5, as fast as I select the "apply changes" in the software properties it reverts back to the open-source drivers.

I opened the the software properties menu through the terminal and this happens when I select `fglrx-updates`:

```
unity-control-center: Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is not installed
                      Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is not installed
                      Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1.1 is not installed
```

and the same happen when `fglrx` is selected.

My system is a DELL INSPIRON 15-5555 with an APU A10 8700P. It has Windows 10 installed by default and secure boot. I don't know if this is important but I added anyway.

Comment: `fglrx` is not supported on 14.04.5.

Comment: Dang! It's there any alternative solution to my predicament? Besides the downgrade and the default open source drivers?